# org.assertj.core.api.Assertions doesNotContain array error

Tags: assert, assertion, katalon-studio, assertj

I wanted to use doesNotContain to make sure the response does not contains the string. but hitting error.

What should be the correct parameter to use?

**test script:**

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*

def testjson= new JsonSlurper().parseText(new String(response.responseText))
println('response text: \n' + JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(testjson)))


assert (testjson.testLines.lineId.contains("test123"))

assert (testjson.testLines.lineId.doesNotContain("test456"))
```

**error**

```
Reason:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.doesNotContain() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [test456]
```

sample response:

```
{
    "testId": "default",
    "createdDate": "2020-05-11T01:51:32.986Z",
    "lastUpdatedDate": "2020-05-11T01:51:32.986Z",
    "testLines": [
        {
            "lineId": "test123",
            "itemId": "test/test123"
        },
        {
            "lineId": "test999",
            "itemId": "test/test999"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining that `doesNotContain()` method expects some other input. I don't know about that method, but if the `contains()` method is working you can just negate the outcome of that one, using "!" in front of a logical statement:

```
assert (!testjson.testLines.lineId.contains("test123"))
```